# How can we add a button over a group having "Join Group"

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Currently i am working with Liferay 6.1.2 with Tomcat. I have my own custom group-management-portlet. How can i add a button (Join Group) on Public view Group and user must join the group.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to [embed a portlet](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Embedding+a+portlet+in+the+theme) in your theme.

First, create a new portlet in your `group-management-portlet` whose sole purpose is this button. Then embed the portlet in your theme at the location of your choosing.